# MYSQL inner join 3rd table sort most recent

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

I have 3 tables, categories / posts / gallery.

Needs to return a list of categories sorted in order of csort with the first gsort photo from the newest post. If no photo or post then show null.

The first photo for each post will generally be gsort=1, however if this photo is removed, it needs to show the lowest gsort value as i will then show a placeholder image.

```
categories
----------
cid cname   curl    csort
1   ccc     ccc/    3   
2   bbb     bbb/    2
3   aaa     aaa/    1
4   ddd     ddd/    4


posts
-----
pid pname   purl            cid padded              poffon
1   apples  apples.html     2   2019-01-02 10:11:12 1
2   orange  orange.html     1   2019-01-02 10:12:00 1
3   grape   red-grapes.html 1   2019-01-06 10:15:12 1
4   banana  bannas.html     2   2019-01-08 10:19:54 0   //Note: this post is hidden
5   kiwi    kiwi-fruit.html 3   2019-01-10 10:26:20 1


gallery_photos
--------------
gid pid gsrc        gsort
1   1   img01a.jpg  6
2   1   img01b.jpg  2
3   1   img01c.jpg  4
4   3   img03a.jpg  2
5   3   img03b.jpg  1
6   3   img03c.jpg  4
7   3   img03d.jpg  3
8   2   img02a.jpg  1
9   1   img01d.jpg  5
10  1   img01e.jpg  3
```

Expected results>>>

```
cid cname   curl    gsrc
3   aaa     aaa/    null        //Note: no photos exist for this post
2   bbb     bbb/    img02a.jpg  //Note: 1 post exists for this category, show gsrc for lowest gsort
1   ccc     ccc/    img03b.jpg  //Note: 2 posts exist for this category, show gsrc for lowest gsort for the latest post date
4   ddd     ddd/    null        //Note: no posts exist for this category... a holding page with other content will be shown
```

Here's what I've got so far for the query BUT its returning too many results:

```
SELECT C.id
     , C.name
     , GA.medium_path AS gsrc
     , GA.gsort
  FROM CATEGORIES C 
  LEFT 
  JOIN POSTS P 
    ON C.cid = P.cid 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT cid
            , MAX(padded) max_date 
         FROM POSTS 
        GROUP 
           BY cid 
        ORDER 
           BY padded DESC
     ) t 
    ON t.max_date = P.padded 
   AND C.cid = P.cid 
  LEFT 
  JOIN GALLERY GA 
    ON GA.pid = P.pid
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using ? It is probably easier to achieve this with 8.0.

Comment: @GMB its v5.5.52, not really an option to change MySQL versions due to other resources requiring this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that extends your logic. It uses a series of `LEFT JOIN`s to identify, then pull out the latest post, and then identify and pull out the earlier picture.

```
SELECT 
    c.cid, 
    c.cname, 
    c.curl,
    g.gsrc, 
    g.gsort 
FROM 
    categories c
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT cid, MAX(padded) padded FROM posts WHERE poffon = 1 GROUP BY cid) pmax ON pmax.cid = c.cid
    LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.cid = c.cid AND p.padded = pmax.padded
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT pid, MIN(gsort) gsort FROM gallery_photos GROUP BY pid) gmin ON gmin.pid = p.pid
    LEFT JOIN gallery_photos g ON g.pid = p.pid AND g.gsort = gmin.gsort
ORDER BY c.cname
```

I tested it in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b80efb07809d6e867193e5799f446d3b) and the result matches your expected output (excepted the `gsrc` for `cid` `2`, which I believe should be `'img01b.jpg'` instead of `'img02a.jpg'`).

```
 WITH
     categories AS (
         SELECT 1 cid, 'ccc' cname, 'ccc/' curl, 3 csort
         UNION SELECT 2, 'bbb', 'bbb/', 2
         UNION SELECT 3, 'aaa', 'aaa/', 1
         UNION SELECT 4, 'ddd', 'ddd/', 4
     ),
     posts AS (
         SELECT 1 pid, 'apples' pname, 'apples.html' purl, 2 cid, '2019-01-02 10:11:12' padded, 1 poffon
         UNION SELECT 2, 'orange', 'orange.html', 1, '2019-01-02 10:12:00', 1
         UNION SELECT 3, 'grape', 'red-grapes.html', 1, '2019-01-06 10:15:12', 1
         UNION SELECT 4, 'banana', 'bannas.html', 2, '2019-01-08 10:19:54', 0
         UNION SELECT 5, 'kiwi', 'kiwi-fruit.html', 3, '2019-01-10 10:26:20', 1
     ),
     gallery_photos AS (
         SELECT 1 gid, 1 pid, 'img01a.jpg' gsrc, 6 gsort
         UNION SELECT 2, 1, 'img01b.jpg', 2
         UNION SELECT 3, 1, 'img01c.jpg', 4
         UNION SELECT 4, 3, 'img03a.jpg', 2
         UNION SELECT 5, 3, 'img03b.jpg', 1
         UNION SELECT 6, 3, 'img03c.jpg', 4
         UNION SELECT 7, 3, 'img03d.jpg', 3
         UNION SELECT 8, 2, 'img02a.jpg', 1
         UNION SELECT 9, 1, 'img01d.jpg', 5
         UNION SELECT 10, 1, 'img01e.jpg', 3
     )
 SELECT 
     c.cid, 
     c.cname, 
     c.curl,
     g.gsrc, 
     g.gsort 
 FROM 
     categories c
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT cid, MAX(padded) padded FROM posts WHERE poffon = 1 GROUP BY cid) pmax ON pmax.cid = c.cid
     LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.cid = c.cid AND p.padded = pmax.padded
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT pid, MIN(gsort) gsort FROM gallery_photos GROUP BY pid) gmin ON gmin.pid = p.pid
     LEFT JOIN gallery_photos g ON g.pid = p.pid AND g.gsort = gmin.gsort
 ORDER BY c.cname;
```

```
 cid | cname | curl | gsrc       | gsort
 --: | :---- | :--- | :--------- | ----:
   3 | aaa   | aaa/ | null       |  null
   2 | bbb   | bbb/ | img01b.jpg |     2
   1 | ccc   | ccc/ | img03b.jpg |     1
   4 | ddd   | ddd/ | null       |  null
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you the results you want. It uses two subqueries; one to get the newest post by category, and the second to get the photo with the lowest `gsort` value for each post. The results of these two subqueries are then `LEFT JOIN`ed to the `categories` table to give the newest post with the lowest `gsort` value per category:

```
SELECT c.*, pm.pid, pm.pname, pm.purl, pm.padded, pm.poffon, gm.gsrc, gm.gsort
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT p.*
           FROM posts p
           JOIN (SELECT cid, MAX(padded) AS latest
                 FROM posts
                 WHERE poffon = 1
                 GROUP BY cid) pl ON pl.cid = p.cid AND pl.latest = p.padded
          ) pm ON pm.cid = c.cid
LEFT JOIN (SELECT g.*
           FROM gallery_photos g
           JOIN (SELECT pid, MIN(gsort) AS earliest
                 FROM gallery_photos
                 GROUP BY pid) ge ON ge.pid = g.pid AND ge.earliest = g.gsort
          ) gm ON gm.pid = pm.pid
ORDER BY cname
```

Output:

```
cid     cname   curl    csort   pid     pname   purl                padded                  poffon  gsrc        gsort
3       aaa     aaa/    1       5       kiwi    kiwi-fruit.html     2019-01-10 10:26:20     1       
2       bbb     bbb/    2       1       apples  apples.html         2019-01-02 10:11:12     1       img01b.jpg  2
1       ccc     ccc/    3       3       grape   red-grapes.html     2019-01-06 10:15:12     1       img03b.jpg  1
4       ddd     ddd/    4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f42bd547be38da306ff7f92288075114)

*Note* I think your expected result for category `bbb` is wrong, for cid=2 the most recent post is post 1, and the lowest gsort value for that post is 2, which corresponds to `img01b`. `img02a` belongs to post 2, which is in cid 1,not 2.